# Linq Multiple Expression

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, conditional-statements

I use ASP.NET and EF5. I need multiple condition with Linq. I need like this sql statement.

```
SELECT * FROM Products 
WHERE (ProdName LIKE '%value1%' AND  ProdName LIKE '%value2%'  AND  ProdName LIKE '%value3%') 
OR (Keywords LIKE '%value4%')
```

How can i convert to linq the above sql. I've write this but it's not enough.

```
var prodQuery = from p in _db.Products
    select new SearchResult
    {
        Product = p,
        SearchResultType = SearchResultType.Prod
    };
//this foreach has to be in brackets in sql
foreach (var s in searchText.Split(' '))
{
    var temp = s;
    prodQuery = prodQuery.Where(x => x.Product.ProdName.Contains(temp));
}

//and this foreach has to be in another bracket in sql and it has to connect with or clause
prodQuery = prodQuery.Where(x => x.Product.Keywords.Contains(searchText));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var keywords = searchText.Split(' ');

var results = _db.Products.Where(p => keywords.Any(kw => kw.Contains(p.ProdName)) 
                              || p.Keywords.Contains(searchText))
                 .Select(x => new SearchResult()
                {
                       Product = x,
                       SearchResultType = SearchResultType.Prod
                });
```

Comment: but containts  doesn't return record as like '%keyword%'

Comment: @Argicx do you mean that your searchText may contain %? Is it legit case?

Comment: yes, firstly split with comma so i've to search every keyword with % wildcard. as this '%keyword%'

Comment: Please provide an example of searchText, for which the problem is not solved